# What's the best practice for handling format qualifiers for images in compute shaders which will operate on multiple image formats?

Tags: graphics, glsl, gpgpu, vulkan

So I am working on a GLSL compute shader for a Vulkan application which will operate on two input images to create an output image.

So far, my layout bindings look like this:

```
layout(binding = 0, rg32f) uniform readonly image2D input1;
layout(binding = 1, rg32f) uniform readonly image2D input2;
layout(binding = 2) uniform writeonly image2D outputImage;
```

I have these declared with a format qualifier, as [according to the spec](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store):

> Image variables can be declared with a format qualifier; this specifies the format for any read operations done on the image. Therefore, a format qualifier is required if you do not declare the variable with the writeonly memory qualifier.

So the thing is, I now want to use this same shader on a second image type: `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` in addition to `VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT`.

What is the best practice for handling this situation?  Is it possible to generalize this shader somehow, or do I need to compile a second shader for the second input format?

Answer (score 3):

> I now want to use this same shader on a second image type: `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` in addition to `VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT`.

These are two *very* different operations, which require very different code on the GPU to be executed. That's why the format is a part of the variable.

However, if you insist on trying to do this with a single shader, you can alias declarations. That is, use the same descriptor set+binding for two different variables, and access the correct one based on a specialization constant or uniform.

Comment: What would be considered best practice?  Compiling two different shaders, or using a specialization constant?  I guess separate shaders seems like it would be more performant?

I am not married to using the same shader, it would just be quite straightforward as the format is literally the only difference between the two invocations.

Comment: There won't be a performance difference between using specialization constants and separate shaders.  If you have:  " if (mySpecConstant == FormatA) { process image formatA} else { process image formatB }"  then the shader compiler in the driver will not generate code for the "if" test and generate code only for the FormatA path if the spec const was set to FormatA.
It will probably boil down to how you want to manage your shader sources.  Spec consts + added parm at pipeline create, OR compile multiple shaders with either single source + preprocessor or separate sources.